# table of content not visible initially

Tags: bookdown

I have written an ebook with bookdown in a gitbook format. I retrieved the html pages so I can upload it to my personal website.

It works like a charm with one exception. The first time the reader views the ebook, the table of content is not visible on the left side. He must click on the small picto 'toggle sidebar' to make it visible.

Is there a way to make the TOC in the sidebar always visible?
If not, how can I make sure it is visible when the user arrives on the ebook at first?

Thanks in advance,

Maxime

[image: Table of Contents not visible at first by the reader]